# Use a function like a class method

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int mazzo[]=new int[40];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mescolamento(mazzo);
    }



    public void mescolamento(int[] array) { //THIS 

        int n = array.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int change = random.nextInt(n -i);
            swap(array, i, change);
        }
    }

    public void swap(int[] mazzo2, int i, int change) {
        int appoggio = mazzo2[i];
        mazzo2[i] =  mazzo2[change];
        mazzo2[change] = appoggio;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to transfer this function into a class?
It works also like this but I need to make the mainActivity clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course . Define your class :

```
public class ActivityHelper{
private int[] array
//declare constructor
public ActivityHelper(int[] array){
this.array = array;
}

public void mescolamento() { 

        int n = array.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int change = random.nextInt(n -i);
            swap(array, i, change);
        }
    }  

 public void swap(int[] mazzo2, int i, int change) {
        int appoggio = mazzo2[i];
        mazzo2[i] =  mazzo2[change];
        mazzo2[change] = appoggio;
    }
}
```

and than in your activity , in onCreate method , remove : `mescolamento()` and add :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  ActivityHelper activityHelper = new ActivityHelper(mazzo);
    acvitivyHelper.mescolamento();
}
```

If you don't want instance of that class create a static method :

```
public class ActivityHelper{

public static void mescolamento(int[] array) { 

        int n = array.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int change = random.nextInt(n -i);
            swap(array, i, change);
        }
    }  

 public static void swap(int[] mazzo2, int i, int change) {
        int appoggio = mazzo2[i];
        mazzo2[i] =  mazzo2[change];
        mazzo2[change] = appoggio;
    }
}
```

And than in your onCreate method :

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityHelper.mescolamento(mezzo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a static method in a different class. The swap method could be private if you wanted. Just depends on if you will use it anywhere else or not.

```
public class ClassName {
    public static void mescolamento(int[] array) { //THIS 

        int n = array.length;
        Random random = new Random();
        random.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            int change = random.nextInt(n -i);
            swap(array, i, change);
        }
    }  



public static void swap(int[] mazzo2, int i, int change) {
        int appoggio = mazzo2[i];
        mazzo2[i] =  mazzo2[change];
        mazzo2[change] = appoggio;
    }
}
```

And then call it with

```
ClassName.mescolamento(array)
```

Comment: you cannot call it like that if it is not static `ClassName.mescolamento(array)` and he also needs the `swap()` method in that class .

Comment: Yup, I forgot to add the static part. Thanks. I only added the one method because it had the comment //THIS next to it. I assumed it was the only one they wanted moved

Comment: and the `swap()` method